# Algorithm to recognize enclosed areas

Tags: algorithm

When I draw freehand lines, curves, circles or any other strokes on a touch screen, I need an algorithm to tell if any enclosed area is formed in a stroke. For example if a lowercase 'e' is drawn, there's an enclosed area in it, but letters like 'm', 'w' don't have any enclosed areas in them.

Comment: Actually I just used 'e' to explain the 'enclosed area' of a symbol. What I wanted to deal with is a series of symbols designed by myself, each one of which has a specific meaning. Once a symbol is drawn, I want the algorithm to tell if there's an enclosed area in it.

Comment: What is the input? Some points on a path? An image? For the latter it will be pretty hard to come up with a performant algorithm.

Comment: Some points on a path.

Answer (score 0):

1. For already existing lines you can pick a pixel on the screen and
   then expand it in all directions stopping at a line until the whole
   area is covered.
2. If you do not consider the screen's borders as an area boundary: You
   can tell if it's an enclosed area by just checking if it hits the
   screen's borders.
3. If you do consider the screen's borders as an area boundary: Then it
   is an enclosed area.
4. Subtract the area you just checked. And pick a new pixel. Repeat until no    pixels are left.

Comment: What I wanted to deal with is a series of symbols designed by myself. Once a symbol is drawn, I want the algorithm to tell if there's an enclosed area in it on the fly, so the algorithm should be able to tell it very quick. It should also be able to tell if it's drawn clockwise or counterclockwise.

Comment: In the comments you said the input consists of a bunch of paths. How about calculating intersections from all the paths and merging all paths with intersections into a graph. Then you could use a graph algorithm to detect loops.

Comment: And those points have probably pixel coordinates, haven't they? Then you can use vector maths to calculate intersections and then join them together in a graph.